# What's the difference between the Browser Object Model and the Document Object Model?

Tags: html, dom, browser

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: I was interested in the difference between platform objects vs browser objects (select list VS Drop Down lists for example) but this is interesting also. +1!

Comment: The [BOM](http://intellectualpirates.net/web-150/lecture-4-debugging/) includes the [Window](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/) and [Navigator](http://devedge-temp.mozilla.org/library/manuals/2000/javascript/1.3/guide/navobj.html) objects, which are used to access information such as the [back button](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript) and [plugin status](http://www.webreference.com/js/column20/mimetypes.html) which is not dependent upon the current document loaded on the page.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The Browser Object Model is a larger representation of everything provided by the browser including the current document, location, history, frames, and any other functionality the browser may expose to JavaScript. The Browser Object Model is not standardized and can change based on different browsers.

The Document Object Model is standardized and is specific to current HTML document.  It is exposed by the Browser Object Model (i.e., DOM is a subset of BOM).

Answer (score 15):

## BOM

This is an informal term as there is no W3C or WHATWG standard that mentions it.

One simple definition would be that the BOM encompasses the entire object structure which is accessible via scripting in the browser, beginning with the `window` object which "contains everything else", since it's the global object.

The `window` object contains lots of properties (try `console.dir( window );`). These properties are specified in numerous web-standards. The "core" specification of the `window` object is as of now still specified in the HTML standard - [see here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object), but I guess it's only a matter of time until the editors decide to transfer this specification into a separate standard. I'm definitively rooting for a "BOM" or "Browser Environment" standard to make things more logical and appropriate.

## DOM

This on the other hand is a formal term. You can find definitions of this term in various standards, for instance the [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/) standard states:

> The DOM is a language- and platform neutral interface that allows
>   programs and scripts to  dynamically access and update the content and
>   structure of documents.

Notice how the emphasis is on documents. Unlike the BOM which is basically and umbrella term for all the APIs in the browsers, DOM are only those APIs which deal with documents.

A simple definition would be that the DOM is implemented as the `document` object (which is the root of the DOM tree btw). Basically, the DOM tree (and everything inside it) can be considered part of the DOM. Analogously, everything beyond the DOM-tree is not part of the DOM.

beyond the DOM-tree == all the properties of `window` except the `document` object

Comment: HTML5 codified much of the BOM as a formal specification. So, there is a standard (sort of), which all the major browser adhere to.

Answer (score 3):

"Browser Object Model" (BOM) is a term from the early 2000s that didn't catch on and was replaced[1] with the term **"Web APIs"**

[Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) are the JavaScript [APIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) available to web pages: any objects/interfaces, their properties, methods, and events the browser makes available to the page, except for the objects, like `String`, that are part of [JavaScript language](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) itself.

[The DOM (Document Object Model)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), in context of web development, is a subset of Web APIs concerned with manipulation of the structure and contents of web pages and other "documents".

Historically, the DOM was designed as "[a platform- and language-neutral interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/#abstract)" with [DOM Level 1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/) describing both the ECMAScript (JavaScript) and Java bindings in appendices. You might still use DOM APIs to work with XML/HTML data from outside the browser (e.g. using [Xerces](https://xerces.apache.org/#xerces2-j) in Java), but the "Living Standard" version of the DOM specification is maintained with the focus on the web use-case, and the most [recent W3C implementation report](http://w3c.github.io/test-results/dom/details.html) includes mainly (if not only) web browsers.

---

[1] See [Google trends for "Browser object model"](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=%2Fm%2F0j24wk_), and how in a modern book (JavaScript Cookbook: Programming the Web) it's [only briefly mentioned as 'BOM - see Web API'](https://books.google.de/books?id=4nJpBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA596&lpg=PA596&dq=%22browser+object+model%22+web+api&source=bl&ots=8QTKoajT5S&sig=ACfU3U3K9-UlCnFMNwZnaqe6xPZW22Qf2g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivvYCbiP3iAhVRJ1AKHd-GB8E4ChDoATAFegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=%22browser%20object%20model%22%20web%20api&f=false).

*[answer rewritten in 2019]*

Comment: Also, if you open the "DOM" tab in Firebug, you'll see JavaScript's global object, which belongs to the BOM, and has little to do with the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

i think `BOM=DOM +(-) non standard properties of the browser`. so every browser has its own BOM

Answer (score 0):

BOM is wider view of entire browser where as DOM is ristricted to document window and associated methods. view complete article 
[javascript-browser-object-model](http://bay-six.blogspot.in/2013/01/javascript-browser-object-model.html)