# What is the DOM and BOM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

What is the DOM and BOM in JavaScript? If someone could explain these in layman terms it would be great! I like to get a deeper understanding of these.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between the Browser Object Model and the Document Object Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213594/whats-the-difference-between-the-browser-object-model-and-the-document-object-m)

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The BOM (Browser Object Model) consists of the objects `navigator`, `history`, `screen`, `location` and `document` which are children of `window`. In the `document` node is the DOM (Document Object Model), the document object model, which represents the contents of the page. You can manipulate it using javascript.

Comment: > In the `document` node is the DOM

I think a better way to describe it is: "node is in the DOM tree" or "node is the smallest unit in the DOM tree" or "nodes compose the DOM tree".

Thoughts?

Comment: the original answer looks perfect to me

Answer (score 47):

- DOM - Document Object Model
- BOM - Browser Object Model

[This article](http://vkanakaraj.wordpress.com/2009/12/18/javascript-vs-dom-vs-bom-relationship-explained/) explains relationship between Javascript, DOM and BOM.

Answer (score 44):

They're just different objects you're dealing with:

- The DOM is the **Document** Object Model, which deals with the document, the HTML elements themselves, e.g. `document` and all traversal you would do in it, events, etc.
- The BOM is the **Browser** Object Model, which deals with browser components aside from the document, like `history`, `location`, `navigator` and `screen` (as well as some others that vary by browser).

Answer (score 6):

DOM means Document Object model..when the webpage is loaded the browser creates a document object model for the page..All the  objects are arranged as tree structure...

BOM means Browser Object Model.window object is supported by all browsers it represents the window browser..All global JavaScript objects, functions, and variables automatically become members of the window object.

Answer (score 4):

You can find more information about Javascript on Mozilla Foundation.

DOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Introduction

BOM

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Browser

Answer (score 4):

DOM :
The document object represents the whole html document. When html document is loaded in the browser, it becomes a document object.

BOM :
The window object represents a window in browser. An object of window is created automatically by the browser.

Answer (score 3):

BOM means Browser Object Model . These are objects that you can use to manipulate the browser. they are navigator

- navigator
- screen
- location
- history
- document

they are all children of the Window Object.
DOM is Document Object Model is part of the BOM and it helps you manipulate the content of the loaded page file. this include the HTML and CSS

Answer (score 3):

DOM -> Document Object Model in JavaScript is the API to access the elements inside the document. It maps the entire Document into an hierarchy of parent and child tree. Each node can hold number of children element or can inherit to other parent element in some or the other way.

BOM ->  Browser Object Model is a larger representation of everything provided by the browser including the current document, location, history, frames, and any other functionality the browser may expose to JavaScript. The Browser Object Model is not standardized and can change based on different browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**BOM** stands for Browser Object Model. Unlike DOM, there is no standard defined for BOM, hence different browsers implement it in different ways. The collection of browser objects is collectively known as the Browser Object Model.

**BOM** main task is to manage browser windows and enable communication between the windows (i.e BOM deals with entire browser). Each HTML page which is loaded into a browser window becomes a Document object and a document object is an object in the BOM. You can say ***BOM** is a superset of DOM*. BOM has many objects, methods, and properties that are not part of the DOM structure.

> while

**DOM** stands for Document Object Model. It is a standard defined by W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) and is specific to current HTML document (i.e DOM deals with document alone). DOM is a programming interface (API) for representing and interacting with HTML, XHTML and XML documents. It organizes the elements of the document in a tree structure (DOM tree) and in the DOM tree, all elements of the document are defined as objects (tree nodes) which have properties and methods.

**DOM** tree objects can be accessed and manipulated with the help of any programming language since it is cross-platform and language-independent. ***DOM** is a subset of BOM*, we can manipulate DOM tree with the help of JavaScript and jQuery for example.[image]

Comment: Can we say BOM is also an API for representing and interacting with a browser window??

Comment: @PrateekGupta Yes, ofcourse BOM is an API. BOM is represented by the `window` object and you can get browser windows width and height with `window.outerWidth`  `window.outerHeight` but one that is not standardized which means though `window.outerWidth` etc exists both in Chrome and Firefox, browser vendors can choose to remove, include, rename to something else or keep same name as other vendors (as they are free to follow their own standard, no set standard :) ).

Answer (score 1):

**What is the DOM?**

The DOM is a W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) standard.

The DOM defines a standard for accessing documents:

"The W3C Document Object Model (DOM) is a platform and language-neutral interface that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document."

**DOM Methods:**
document.getElementById(id)
document.getElementsByTagName(name)
document.getElementsByClassName(name)
document.createElement(element)
document.removeChild(element)

**Properties:**
document.body
document.cookie
document.doctype
document.documentElement
document.documentMode

[More details](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)

**The Browser Object Model (BOM)**
There are no official standards for the Browser Object Model (BOM).

Since modern browsers have implemented (almost) the same methods and properties for JavaScript interactivity, it is often referred to, as methods and properties of the BOM. It consists:

- window
- screen
- location
- history
- navigator
- popup alert
- timing
- cookies

[More Details](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp)