# What is the DOM and BOM in JavaScript and if BOM is an object how to access it?

Tags: javascript

There are many question i saw on these concept still i have some doubts that's why asking specifically
What is Browser object Model is this any object in javascript if it is how to access that object and what kind of properties it has
someone please clarify exact definition of each

For example window is a global object created by Javascript engine

We can access it by

```
window
```

when we say window we get following properties in console

```
window
Window {speechSynthesis: SpeechSynthesis, caches: CacheStorage, localStorage: Storage, sessionStorage: Storage, webkitStorageInfo: DeprecatedStorageInfo…}
```

When we say

```
 window.document
 #document<html>​<head>​

​</head>​<body>​…​</body>​<script src=​"app.js">​</script>​</body>​</html>​
```

Similar way what is BOM and DOM

Comment: [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model), [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document) - and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416317/what-is-the-dom-and-bom-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The BOM consists of the objects `navigator`, `history`, `screen`, `location` and `document` which are children of `window`. In the `document` node is the DOM, the document object model, which represents the contents of the page. You can manipulate it using javascript.

Reference

[What is the DOM and BOM in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416317/what-is-the-dom-and-bom-in-javascript/4416337#4416337)

Answer (score 0):

All browsers are split into different parts (objects) that can be accessed using Javascript. Collectively, these parts are known as the Browser Object Model, or the BOM. At the very top of this browser hierarchy is the Window object. This represents the entire browser, with its toolbars, menus, status bar, the page itself, and a whole lot more besides. Effectively, the Window IS the browser.

Every web page resides inside a browser window which can be considered as an object.

A Document object represents the HTML document that is displayed in that window. The Document object has various properties that refer to other objects which allow access to and modification of document content.

Answer (score 0):

**BOM** stands for ***Browser Object Model***

**DOM** stands for ***Document Object Model***

**Document** is a document object constructor

**window** is a scripting handle for window object

Comment: Clearly the OP knows what the acronym BOM is short for, as they stated it in the question

Answer (score 0):

With **Browser Object Model**(window Object), you can:

- Manipulate the browser window with the window object and things like
  scrolling, opening a new window, closing the current window, ..Etc.
- Use the object document property to interact with the DOM.
- Get the browser history with the history object.
- Manipulate the screen with the screen object.
- Get and do things with the location object.

With **DOM** you can:

- Change an element text.
- Change an HTML element color.
- Hide and show elements
- Make an HTML elements listen to an event