# Is there any standard for WEB/DOM/BOM API

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

Is there any standard for WEB/DOM/BOM API which all browsers adhere to? Something like ECMAScript.

```
var aElements = document.querySelectorAll('a');
```

How to make sure the line mentioned above works across the browsers I intend to support?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll, under "Specifications"

Comment: Also, a useful resource for quick checking: https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org, but standards don’t tell the whole browser support story. For that, see sites like https://caniuse.com.

Comment: Does W3C has anything to do with dom? I also found https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_engines_(DOM_support) . Is it reliable?

Comment: @blueray W3 and WHATWG are different organisations, where WHATWG sprung from the former because they didn't like the way W3 was governed and the way it developed standards. They still compete in the sense that W3 these days aligns some of their specifications with what WHATWG publishes, but which is _the_ authority on an API cannot be answered -- those who make Web browsers have to decide that themselves as they implement APIs. In short -- yes, there is a DOM standard, actually many, by at least two standards bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes (in most cases), there is standards.

Practically, no, you can't be *sure* something works cross browser. For that you need to test it on all you intend to support.

*Below you find some useful links, where others have made some of these tests, and put it together, to make life somewhat simpler for us developers...so a big **Thank you** to them, as official resources can be a pain to read and understand.*

The reason is quite simple, browser manufacturer can, and sometimes do, interpret set standards in their own way, which can lead to different behavior (often called "browser bugs").

There is also the time between a given standard is set to take into account, and for *all* manufacturer to actually implement it. This is often where *prefixed* properties comes into play, before drafted new/updated properties have been standardized.

Some useful links:

- [Looking for official docs for all Javascript (BOM, DOM, built-in) Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56370293/looking-for-official-docs-for-all-javascript-bom-dom-built-in-objects)
- [What's the difference between the Browser Object Model and the Document Object Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213594/whats-the-difference-between-the-browser-object-model-and-the-document-object-m)
- [Where is the JavaScript DOM API documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768606/where-is-the-javascript-dom-api-documented)
- https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/javascript/dom-bom
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API
- https://caniuse.com/
- https://quirksmode.org/

Comment: What is https://dom.spec.whatwg.org & https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-dom-20151119/

Comment: @blueray -- They are new and old versions of the same. The first is where we are at today, the second is where we were 4 years ago. In the second/old there's a link labeled "Latest published version:". Click that and you get to the first/new address.